# How to write S3 bucket policy to disable bulk delete at once inside a folder in s3 bucket but allow users to download it individually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket with the following structures.

```
/
|-- folder1
|   |-- img1.jpg
|   |-- img2.jpg
|   |-- img3.jpg
|   `-- somedata
|       `-- file.mp3
`-- folder2
    |-- img1.jpg
    |-- img2.jpg
    |-- img3.jpg
    `-- somedata
        `-- file.mp3
```

Now, I don't want any user to delete the contents of any folders i.e. `folder1` or `folder2` at once, but if they want they can do it individually, one at a time. Like delete `folder1/img1.jpg`, `folder1/img2.jpg` but should not be able to select `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, `img3.jpg`, `somedata/file.mp3` from the console and delete in one go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command in Amazon S3 to "delete folders". Each object must be deleted individually.

Even if you use a utility such as the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), it simply loops through the objects and deletes them one-at-a-time.

So, users cannot actually "delete folders". Thus, it is not possible to 'disable bulk delete' since there *is* no bulk delete capability. (Unless you use Amazon S3 Lifecycle.)